# Fastest way to combine multiple csv files based on 1st column value

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

So lets say I have 5 csv files (created in order from 1 to 5) with 8-10 columns each. Each file has about 300,000 (give or take) rows each.

Each file should match the value (unique) from the first column in every file, and then combine the records + column title(s). If files 2 through 5 do not have it's value from column 1 found in file1 (from column 1), the entire row should be excluded from the merging.

Example below of two (out of 5) csv files...

File1

```
ColumnTitle1,ColumnTitle2,ColumnTitle3,ColumnTitle4,ColumnTitle5,ColumnTitle6,ColumnTitle7,ColumnTitle8,ColumnTitle9,ColumnTitle10
Column1Value3145,Column2Value1,Column3Value1,Column4Value1,Column5Value1,Column6Value1,Column7Valu1,Column8Value1,Column9Value1,Column10Value1
Column1Value573,Column2Value2,Column3Value2,Column4Value2,Column5Value2,Column6Value2,Column7Valu2,Column8Value2,Column9Value2,Column10Value2
Column1Value62317,Column2Value3,Column3Value3,Column4Value3,Column5Value3,Column6Value3,Column7Valu3,Column8Value3,Column9Value3,Column10Value3
Column1Value93,Column2Value4,Column3Value4,Column4Value4,Column5Value4,Column6Value4,Column7Valu4,Column8Value4,Column9Value4,Column10Value4
```

File2:

```
ColumnTitle1,ColumnTitle11,ColumnTitle12,ColumnTitle13,ColumnTitle14,ColumnTitle15,ColumnTitle16,ColumnTitle17,ColumnTitle18
Column1Value752789,Column11Value1,Column12Value1,Column13Value1,Column14Value1,Column15Value1,Column16Value1,Column17Value1,Column18Value1
Column1Value3145,Column11Value2,Column12Value2,Column13Value2,Column14Value2,Column15Value2,Column16Value2,Column17Value2,Column18Value2
Column1Value573,Column11Value3,Column12Value3,Column13Value3,Column14Value3,Column15Value3,Column16Value3,Column17Value3,Column18Value3
Column1Value832657,Column11Value4,Column12Value4,Column13Value4,Column14Value4,Column15Value4,Column16Value4,Column17Value4,Column18Value4
Column1Value62317,Column11Value5,Column12Value5,Column13Value5,Column14Value5,Column15Value5,Column16Value5,Column17Value5,Column18Value5
Column1Value93,Column11Value6,Column12Value6,Column13Value6,Column14Value6,Column15Value6,Column16Value6,Column17Value6,Column18Value6
Column1Value423568,Column11Value7,Column12Value7,Column13Value7,Column14Value7,Column15Value7,Column16Value7,Column17Value7,Column18Value7
```

If I were to just merge these two files (2 out of the 5) it would look something like this:

```
ColumnTitle1,ColumnTitle2,ColumnTitle3,ColumnTitle4,ColumnTitle5,ColumnTitle6,ColumnTitle7,ColumnTitle8,ColumnTitle9,ColumnTitle10,ColumnTitle11,ColumnTitle12,ColumnTitle13,ColumnTitle14,ColumnTitle15,ColumnTitle16,ColumnTitle17,ColumnTitle18
Column1Value3145,Column2Value1,Column3Value1,Column4Value1,Column5Value1,Column6Value1,Column7Valu1,Column8Value1,Column9Value1,Column10Value1,Column11Value2,Column12Value2,Column13Value2,Column14Value2,Column15Value2,Column16Value2,Column17Value2,Column18Value2
Column1Value573,Column2Value2,Column3Value2,Column4Value2,Column5Value2,Column6Value2,Column7Valu2,Column8Value2,Column9Value2,Column10Value2,Column11Value3,Column12Value3,Column13Value3,Column14Value3,Column15Value3,Column16Value3,Column17Value3,Column18Value3
Column1Value62317,Column2Value3,Column3Value3,Column4Value3,Column5Value3,Column6Value3,Column7Valu3,Column8Value3,Column9Value3,Column10Value3,Column11Value5,Column12Value5,Column13Value5,Column14Value5,Column15Value5,Column16Value5,Column17Value5,Column18Value5
Column1Value93,Column2Value4,Column3Value4,Column4Value4,Column5Value4,Column6Value4,Column7Valu4,Column8Value4,Column9Value4,Column10Value4,Column11Value6,Column12Value6,Column13Value6,Column14Value6,Column15Value6,Column16Value6,Column17Value6,Column18Value6
```

Adding files 3 - 5 would increase the columns to around 50 (give or take).

I'm not sure if this is the quickest method, but here is the logic I am thinking (which I'm not sure how to do using powershell):

- Go one file at a time to match and merge with file one
- store file1 in variable
- store file2 in variable
- Loop through lines in file1
- \\\\ Where value1 in column1 from file1 is found in column1 from file2
- \\\\ append row from file2 to row in file1
- \\\\ remove row from file2 (lessen the search during the next loop iteration)
- clear variable holding file2
- store next file in variable
- repeat the loop find and append iterations

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: Are you asking about merging or joining objects?

Comment: You may not know how to do it in powershell yet, but a quick google search for each step in your recipe will go a long way. You are on the right track. We're not here to do your work for you, but when you have a script that's broken, we will gladly help you fix the problem. You won't learn without trying and failing yourself. :-)

Comment: Is this a repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755293/compare-and-merge-2-csv-files-based-on-2-first-columns-with-possible-duplicate-v

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, the programming question and answer site where people will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry if I offended anyone as this was not my intention. I do have code that works for this, but it does it only 1 column at a time which would take like 70hrs. Instead, I wanted to see if there was a way to just merge the whole row based upon the first column value matching in both rows. It looks like Frode F. got it. Some of that syntax is new to me, and I probably would not have got it otherwise. Thanks Frode :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All roads lead to Rome. One of them is:

```
#Hashtable to store master-objects in
$data = @{}

#Import-CSV -Filter "MyMasterList.csv" | Foreach-Object { $data[$_.ColumnTitle1] = $_ }
#Sampledata below
@"
ColumnTitle1,ColumnTitle2,ColumnTitle3,ColumnTitle4,ColumnTitle5,ColumnTitle6,ColumnTitle7,ColumnTitle8,ColumnTitle9,ColumnTitle10
Column1Value3145,Column2Value1,Column3Value1,Column4Value1,Column5Value1,Column6Value1,Column7Valu1,Column8Value1,Column9Value1,Column10Value1
Column1Value573,Column2Value2,Column3Value2,Column4Value2,Column5Value2,Column6Value2,Column7Valu2,Column8Value2,Column9Value2,Column10Value2
Column1Value62317,Column2Value3,Column3Value3,Column4Value3,Column5Value3,Column6Value3,Column7Valu3,Column8Value3,Column9Value3,Column10Value3
Column1Value93,Column2Value4,Column3Value4,Column4Value4,Column5Value4,Column6Value4,Column7Valu4,Column8Value4,Column9Value4,Column10Value4
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | % { $data[$_.ColumnTitle1] = $_ }

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\MyOtherCSVs" -Filter "*.csv" | ForEach-Object { Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName } | ForEach-Object {
    $ID = $_.ColumnTitle1

    #If row is in MasterList
    if($data.ContainsKey($ID)) {
        #Get matching object
        $obj = $data[$ID]
        #Foreach line in csv
        $_.psobject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'ColumnTitle1' } | ForEach-Object {
            #Foreach property, add to master-object
            Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
        }
        #Put modified object back into hashtable
        $data[$ID] = $obj
    }
}

$data.Values | Export-Csv -Path "MergedCSV.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Be sure to pack some extra memory with large CSV-files.

Comment: I agree with you on the roads to Rome. I was trying to figure out a way to not do this 1 column at a time (with 52columns and 300,000 records, this would just take forever), and instead just do this as the whole line at a time. This is looking good so far. I'm just waiting for the csv files to be created before I test this.

Comment: takes about an hour in a half to merge 2 files, but it looks like it's working. Will probably take about 12hrs to merge all files, but unless they want to upgrade ram to have more than 2gigs, this is just what they are going to have to deal with. Thanks.

Comment: You could run a similar approach by reading it as text, splitting away first column and use that as ID in the hashtable and append to the string each time it matches. However, what happends if none of the rows in one file matches IDs in file1? How do you know when to include the columntitles? Becuase you would have to add blank values `,,,,,` for the lines that are missing in one file, but present in another etc. Didn't have time for that, but a google search will go a long way. :-)